# some puzzled about java aqs source code about "help gc"

Tags: java, concurrency

When I read the source code of Java AQS, I see the method `acquireQueued` with annotation `help gc` sets `p.next = null`.

If it releases memory for `p`, then why does it need to set `p.next` to `null`?

[image]

Comment: Please include code as text (using the code formatting button) rather than as an image of code.

Answer (score 0):

It means it's helping the garbage collector by setting that variable to `null`, so that its previous value will become unreachable (assuming it's not reachable through some other variable) and thus collectible, without having to establish the unreachability of `p`.

Comment: The Java VM doesn't use references, so values don't become unreferenced in that sense. It's not completely clear to me from this fragment whether `p` (and thus `p.next`) would be unreachable (and thus reclaimable) immediately after `setHead(node)`; if so, then setting `p.next` to `null` may not be necessary.

Comment: Paradoxically, in fact, since `p.next` is mutated *after* the call to `setHead(node)`, it may in fact pin the node pointed to by `p` and *prevent* it from becoming unreachable any earlier.

Comment: In fact, the real explanation is to do with cross-generational links / "floating garbage"; see dup.

Comment: @DanielPryden thanks for your answer